# Java fails to verify signature made with eToken

Tags: java, security, cryptography

The global task is to make client authenticate with a USB-token and establish TLS/SSL connection to a Java server. But the server responds "certificate verify message signature error" everytime.
We decided to try signing and verifying a message with the token. And... It fails! A message signed with the token's private key isn't verified by its own public key. I'm frustrated. Did anyone face such troubles?

Here's the server's stack trace:

```
Exception on read(write) data from socket:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: certificate verify message signature error
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:231)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientCertificateVerify(ServerHandshaker.java:1165)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:220)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181) ...
```

To test signing/verifying I changed [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html) on digital signatures to operate with PKCS11 tokens. Here are the [generator](http://snipt.org/ughih8) and [verifier](http://snipt.org/ughii9).

Comment: are you sure SSL is properly set up ? Keystore is correctly referenced ? The system property is pointing to the real thing ? Also do check for unlocked JSE jars (if by chance you're using keys with more than 128 bits). SSL error messages are always a nightmare.

Comment: @BigMike, yes, these things are ok. Anyway, even if we forget the SSL, signing must work. I wonder why it doesn't. It's like the token doesn't trust itself.

Comment: ok, sorry for the silly question, but SSL is a real nightmare. The only thing that comes to mind is something related to the keys (so the bit on the unlocked jse security jars, but that would have give another error).

Comment: @Andrey Regarding the signature test case you can try to use the private key public key and decrypt the signature (works with RSA only) and verify the signature content using an ASN.1 parser (especially the embedded signature hash).

Comment: It's troubleshooting, but it seems to me that the CA certificate that is used to verify the client certificate has a public key that doesn't match with the one that signed the client certificate. Can you post the base64 (or PEM) encoded certificates? As for verifying a signed message; yes, you *should* be able to do that only with the corresponding public key.